# Program NAETO Robot using ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. I have performed 20 online tutorials. But still not know how to start program naeto robot. Its vacuum cleaner but I want to control it. Kindly guide me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156671/program-naeto-robot-using-ros/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick google search for "ROS neato" turns up the [neato_robot](http://wiki.ros.org/neato_robot) package. It helps if you spell "Neato" properly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2